# Does "scale" mean "achieve", "plan" or some other meaning here?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/NHTJPd7cnBU?t=135)  (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> Grylls lived his childhood dream to climb Everest when he **scaled** earth's highest mountain
>   in 1998, less than two years after his near-fatal Africa fall.

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scale) gives these explanations

> a set of numbers, amounts, etc., used to measure or compare the level of something
>
> the relation between the real size of something and its size on a map, model, or diagram
>
> the size or level of something, especially when this is large

None is suitable in this case.

Does "scale" mean "achieve", "plan" or some other meaning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right page of the dictionary. I wonder why you stopped at the third definition :-)

The *eighth* definition is:

> **scale** *verb* [T] (CLIMB)
>
> to climb up a steep surface, such as a wall or the side of a mountain,
>   often using special equipment:
>
> The prisoner scaled the high prison wall and ran off.

Comment: (To OP) When looking up words in the dictionary which have many meanings, it can be useful to note the part of speech of the word. In your sentence the word is clearly used as a verb, but the first three definitions you found were nouns. Most dictionaries separate the definitions of noun forms from those of verb forms, etc.